# Can a column in a table be both a primary key and also a foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql

Can somebody please tell me if it's okay to have a foreign key act as a primary key in a table?

Example is, I have a `PATIENT` table with `PATIENT_ID` as a primary key, and I'd also like to have `PATIENT_ID` as foreign key and at the same time a primary key to `ASSESSMENT` table (which contains the vital signs of the patient). Is it OK or is it going to produce problems?

Comment: It is ok:). I think no problems here.

Comment: If you have 1 to 1 relation than you should think about merging these two tables into one table.

Comment: [3.6.6. Using Foreign Keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: If a PATIENT can have many ASSESSMENT entries (one for every time he has been monitored) then it's wrong. So, it depends if it's a ONE to ONE relation or ONE to MANY.

Answer (score 4):

That is OK as long as you can maintain a 1 to 1 relation . 
There is no restriction from database side

Answer (score 1):

yes foreign key can work as a primary key in a table.

Comment: can you give some more explanation?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok or is it going to produce problems?

I'd say it is okay. A little problem this produces is maybe that it made you need to ask the question. So if you actually want to learn more you should ask yourself about why specific you are unsure so that you can actually learn something.

Comment: My mileage differed slightly. In my case, I was quite certain about *why* I would want it. I just wasn't able to find a clear statement in the DBMS documentation that it would be accepted. I guess if I hadn't found a written answer here (or somewhere), I would have ended up just trying it to see what would happen. At least now I'll know that, in the unlikely event that it doesn't work, it's a product problem rather than a conceptual problem.

Comment: It is very often that one indexed column (key) of one table also works as a foreign key to another table. As the primary key is also the identifying column, this actually is *damn pretty often* the case.

Comment: But @hakre, wait: if table A has primary key A_id, and table B simply references A_id as a foreign key, that's just the everyday case -- which I think your comment is addressing. What the OP and I are looking to do is "borrow" certain values of A_id and use them as values of B's primary key B_id. In this case, B_id would be _both_ B's primary key and a foreign key referencing A_id -- which is a bit more exotic. (But I admit that I'm confused by your phrase "foreign key *to* another table": which direction is the reference relationship between your "one table" and your "another table"?)

Answer (score 1):

This is called a one-to-one relation.

> Is it ok or is it going to produce problems?

It is OK as long as you have a good reason for keeping the data into two tables.

Answer (score 0):

The prerequisite for a foreign key is that the column being a foreign key needs to be a key in both the tables. So from this point of view, you are perfectly safe. The only problem that can get raised is for future developments in the application, when you might need to have a one to many relation between the 2 tables, in which case it is pretty bad to use this approach. It will not be very hard to change this behavior later on on the database level, but it might prove to be quite tricky at the application level.

Honestly i pretty much doubt you need to actually use a foreign key between the 2 tables, since the ids will always be the same, and this kind of defeats the purpose of a foreign key. Also, most primary keys are usually auto incremented which is not the case for you, and this could lead to other problems in future development.